# OpenGL Updating VBO data by re-specification

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to change the contents of a VBO, but it's for a stream draw so I'm trying to understand and follow the concept explained [here](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object_Streaming) (and [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices)), but I'm getting an error when I attempt that.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
void Model::Draw()
{
    //Changing only the vertexesVBO
    _vertexes[0] += 0.0001f;
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vboVertexes._bufferID);

    //This works
    //glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(float), &_vertexes[0]);

    //But this doesn't
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, _vertexCount * sizeof(float), _vertexes);

    //Call vertexVBO, uvVBO, indexIBO, disable them
}
```

Supposedly, I'm creating a new BufferData of size _vertexCount * sizeof(float) and uninitialized data, and uploading the same **_vertexes** data to it to be used in the next draw call.
But this is throwing the error of access violation reading.

How do I get this working?
And if I understood correctly, with this I shouldn't need to implement a double buffer VBO for animation, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Supposedly, I'm creating a new BufferData of size _vertexCount * sizeof(float) and uninitialized data, and uploading the same _vertexes data to it to be used in the next draw call.

No. You just create a new buffer storage of size **0**. Anf theupdate with `glBufferSubData()` will fail as it is accesing the buffer out of bounds.